# About partial fraction decomposition in Michael Spivak's "Calculus". Why degree 8?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, partial-fractions

I am reading Michael Spivak's "Calculus" now.
I cannot understand why the degree of the polynomial in the picture below is 8.
I think the degree is 7.

[image]

Comment: You're right. It's a typo.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jose Carlos Santos.